# How to achieve this Gradient (Done in Figma with layer Blur)

Tags: gradient, background, blur, gradient-mesh, figma

how can i achieve this Gradient? I know its done in Figma with multiple rectangles and a bunch of Layer Blur. I'm a noob with the Gradient Mesh Tool in Illustrator, so Figma would be easier for me. Especially the smooth transition at the bottom is just stunning, as well as the color range.

I would appreciate any tips, thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Why dont you do a blur just like in figma?

Comment: @joojaa thats what i want to do, but im more interested in placement of the objects, used colors and amount of layering to achieve this gradient.

Comment: Not a problem if your not raster averse. Just place blocks and apply the blur to a group.

Comment: As for "the colour range", make sure your document is in RGB, not CMYK, because there are colours in the example which are out of gamut for CMYK.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a radial gradient from a color to transparent and after that, you can add another radial gradient with different color to same layer. You can add infinite numbers of gradient fills to a shape and you can play with their blender modes until you get the effect you want.